# Events not showing up on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase and Google Tag Manager together to see hits on firebase and google analytics. Do I need to setup and fire tags explicitly for firebase as well in GTM as at the moment I am not able to see any activity on Firebase console. I have setup google analytics tags and when I am pushing data into firebase from Android it is showing on Google Analytics console but not on Firebase, therefore do I need to setup firebase tags as well in GTM console along with firing event through firebase only.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("communication", "communication");
 bundle.putString("call", "call");
firebase.logEvent("call", bundle);
```

This call event is showing up on google analytics but now on Firebase console, can someone please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Firebase with GTM, you need to create one Firebase tag in GTM and trigger it for every event. In this way you can see all your events in Firebase.

Hope this would help.